# css javascript links

Tags: javascript, html, css

This should be very simple, but its not working!

I have this link on my page;

```
<a class='action' href='javascript:void(0)' OnClick='run()'> run </a>
```

And then this css

```
.action {
    color: #e17009;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

For some reason it just shows up black, i can change the size etc.. but the colour doesnt work?

This link is generated with some jquery, and is refreshed, but don think that would make any differance?

Comment: Use firebug. Or other similar tools, such as Chrome's Developer Tools. Even IE has something similar, I think you press F12 to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color declaration is being ignored because of a previous directive, or overwritten by a later one. Try changing the selector to the more explicit `a.action` or using `color: #e17009 !important;`. If that doesn't work, view the parsed CSS values using Firebug.

Comment: @Lunar Don't use !important. Use the Chrome dev tools to find out which CSS rule is overwriting the .action rule's color property.

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing your local css cache (CTRL+F5).
If still not working, inspect your link with Firebug : what is css class making the link color black ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is *jQuery tagged*, but your anchor should look like:

```
<a class='action' href='#' OnClick='run();return false;'> run </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Réjôme, use Firebug - I suspect that, following loading this css, you are loading another file that is overriding the anchor color. Firebug will make it clear where the color is coming from.